# Checkout button in searchbar or not

Tags: usability, search-results, shopping-cart

I'm making a UI for a webshop for internal users. 
They're using our site for placing their orders for their store.

Because they know what to search for, their search queries are very precise.

My idea was to create a category-page-list type results dropdown, so the user can add to his basket directly from searchbar.

Is this a good idea?

[image]

Comment: I've added the image inline rather than as a link off elsewhere incase that link goes down. Although it's an axure link there doesn't seem to be any interactivity there, it's just a screenshot so can fit fine inline here.

Comment: yep indeed, there is no interactivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few snags with this model:-

1. **The Quantity selector**. It is good that you thought of this and added it to the search bar. But, it becomes complex when a user adds certain quantity of a thing to the basket. And then when they search, we should show them the current quantity. If any change is done to the number, then the button should change to 'Update Basket' or something. Basically, the fact is: it becomes convoluted.
2. **How often** does people use this? you have not mentioned particularly about the products listed in your site. So I assume it consits of some which are less expensive and some that are costly. People do not actually buy off something just like that. They need to check the specifications, description, warranty and reviews before buying something. Therefore, a big research needs to be done on 'How often' does one use this.
3. **Size & Colour**. Some items have size and colour selectors too. This comes on top of quantity. It cannot be included in this model.

[image]

4. (Bonus Point) From a business point of view: We will not be able to show add-ons of the products that people generally buy together with this. Like: Mobile+Mobile Case+Headset.

---

**Conclusion**: This model can be used for basic shops only, where the users are well aware of the 'search-lists/items in the shop'.

### A simple alternative would be to add a "Favourite/Add to Wishlist/Buy Later" button.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've missed this thread for a while.

The users indeed know and are very well aware of the content of the shop (they are our internal users). They don't necessarily use the shop for information gathering, just placing their orders. Therefore, also reading your feedback, I think there are no big drawbacks and it's a good concept.

Comment: @I.T. Great.. I think then you could bring this question and discussion to a closure.